# "tested in" or "tested on"

Tags: word-choice

When we open an issue, we write a small report with the testing results. At the end, we note which of the environments the issue was tested in.

I'm not sure if we should use

```
Tested *in* environment 1
```

or

```
Tested *on* environment 2
```

Which one should we use?

EDIT: These environments are not "physical" environments, they are more like different configurations in which the software could be tested. So when I say "tested in/on environment 1" does not mean I'm doing it in a particular place.

Thank you very much

Comment: One usually tests "in" an environment, "on" a platform/operating system, or "with" other software. The distinction between these is fuzzy, though. You also might test it, say, "_using_ Chrome" or "_under IE Explorer_"

Comment: Your opening paragraph needs "in" at the end  ("...tested in.")

Comment: @BrianHitchcock many would add the "in" before "which" rather than at the end.

Comment: @BrianHitchcock Sorry, I really can't help myself here - you're saying "Internet Explorer Explorer" ;) But you still earnt my +1!

Comment: Duh. At first I wrote IE, and then decided I'd spell it out—only got halfway there!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would use ***"tested under X configuration"*** or ***"tested under/on X operating system/platform"***

Comment: @BrianHitchcock: edited answer to correct it, thank you!